# Error with constructor class?

Tags: java, constructor

I writing a class and a program for generating quiz average for a specific student.

I'm not sure if I have an error in the main class or in the StudentClass one but every time I run the program, both values it prints out are 0.

Can anyone see an issue with the code that would cause this? This is the main class:

```
public class Student {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StudentClass quizzes = new StudentClass();

    int[] quizArray = {54, 85, 32, 98, 43, 89};

    quizzes.addQuiz(quizArray[0]);
    quizzes.addQuiz(quizArray[1]);
    quizzes.addQuiz(quizArray[2]);
    quizzes.addQuiz(quizArray[3]);
    quizzes.addQuiz(quizArray[4]);
    quizzes.addQuiz(quizArray[5]);

    int total = quizzes.getTotalScore();
    int average = quizzes.getQuizAverage();

    System.out.println("Total score: " + total);
    System.out.println("Quiz average: " + average);



        }

    }
```

This is the StudentClass:

```
public class StudentClass {
private String name;
private static int numberQuizzes;
private int average;
private int score;
private int total;

public String getName(String name) {
    return this.name;

}

public int addQuiz(int score){
    numberQuizzes++;
    return score;
}

public int getTotalScore(){
    total += score;
    return total;

}

public int getQuizAverage(){
    average = total / numberQuizzes;
    return average;

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add quiz scroe inside `addQuiz` instead of `getTotalScore` method. Move this line:

```
 total += score;
```

This way you will calculate total every quiz added.

Answer (score 1):

The method addQuiz doesn't appear to do anything with the score (such as add it to the total).

getTotalScore() seems to be confused about what 'score' is as well. I wouldn't think you'd want a 'total' type method to add to any member/field, but rather just return the total.

Untested, but try:

```
public int addQuiz(int score){
    numberQuizzes++;
    total += score;
    return score;
}

public int getTotalScore(){
    return total;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you placed the "total += score;" in the wrong method. consequently, the internal values inside your student class is never updated.

remember to initialize your class.
I've added some comments in the codes.

```
public class StudentClass {
private String name;
private static int numberQuizzes =0 ; //increment this every time addQuiz is called
// private int average; // you do not need this...you can re-calculate this
// private int score; //you do not need this.
private int total =0 ; //update your total score on addQuiz()

public int addQuiz(int score){
    numberQuizzes++;
    //update the total score everytime addQuiz() is called.
    total+= score; // this line is missing in your codes.

    return score;
}

public int getTotalScore(){
    // total += score; // this line is redundant.
    return total; 
}

public int getQuizAverage(){
    if(numberQuizzes==0) return 0; //prevent div by zero exception

    return total / numberQuizzes; 

}
```